# How to limit the number of visible pages in pagination with (JavaScript-Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, pagination

I want to create a page layout without using a plugin.

The current page is like this and brings up all the pages.
[image]

**But I want the page to show me that way.**

**in page 1**

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... // selected 1
```

**in page 2**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... //selected 2
```

**in page 3**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... //selected 3
```

**... in page 7**

```
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ... // selected 7
```

**The Html code is written as follows**

```
<nav>
        <ul data="@Model.TotalPage" data-id="@Model.CurrentPageNumber" class="pagination justify-content-center">
            @{
                for (int i = 1; i <= Model.TotalPage; i++)
                {
                    <li class="page-item @(i == Model.CurrentPageNumber ? "active" : "")">
                        <a class="bPageNumber page-link">@i</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think wrap both component in a single component
like
pagesComponent
Slider // it may be your pagination

"When Pages component will render it will pass the hard core data to slider like
page component 1

page component 1 ? slider will be 1,2,3,4 : page compoenent 2 ? slider will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and so one
"

Comment: Is it possible to do this with JavaScript? That is, I give it TotalPage and CurrentPage and then it returns an array of numbers to me and I display it.

Comment: Yes you can do this with javascript simply pass the certain values to slider on the behalf of the rendring of pages
i think its easier than for your condition